# IE8 errors when I try to call a function on the parent page from inside an iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I have a parent page with a function coded like this:

```
function testfunction() {
    alert('hi');
}
```

That page has an iFrame coded like this:

```
<iframe src="testinside.htm"></iframe>
```

Testinside.htm has this link that calls the function on the parent page:

```
<a href="#" onclick="parent.testfunction();">Test</a>
```

In FireFox and Chrome, this all works just fine, but in IE8, I get this error message:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the script section to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testfunction() {
        alert('hi');
    }
</script>
```

and the iframe to:

```
<iframe src="http://www.psychiatrist.com/psychstalk/test/testinside.htm"></iframe>
```

then make sure you load the test with this url:

```
http://www.psychiatrist.com/psychstalk/test/test.htm
```

For some reason the script must be type "text/javascript" for it to work.  The next problem is cross domain issues.  The iframe `src` must match exactly the url of the parent.

Comment: I could kiss you right now, it turns out IE8 acts really strangely (no parent, no window.parent objects) if the type is set to anything other than "text/javascript"

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `window.parent.testfunction()`? I seem to recall an issue similar to this.

Have you tried defining the parent function as

`window.testfunction = function(){}...`

I'm just trying to guess at why IE would fail on this. Perhaps global functions aren't automatically bound to `window` in IE.

If you can't figure this out, you could try polling from the parent to the child, waiting for some `hasBeenClicked` method to return `true`.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that `parent` only refers to the parent frame, not the parent frame's global object. If that doesn't work, try `window.parent.window.testfunction()`

Comment: Regrettably, I have tried that, too. I'll try window.parent.window.parent, though.

Comment: window.testfunction = function(){} works fine in FF, but still not in IE. I would have figured this would have been something that came up before, but hours of searching yesterday, and I have turned nothing up. If anyone cares to look at the live page, go here: http://www.psychiatrist.com/psychstalk/test/test.htm

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, but its maddening that such a (you'd think) simple thing would be so hard.

Comment: @F. Grant - *what* is what you ended up doing? window.parent.window.fn() or window.parent.window.parent.fn() or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

I was trying to access a variable defined in the parent iframe
`<script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"/>` file without success, but when I moved the variable definition into the body of the iframe in `<script type="text/javascript"> var myVar = ""</script>` all works.